# Html pre fill form and execute filter

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website and want to have links to a page which has a filter function. I would like to create a link in such a way that when followed I do not simply get the destination page, but rather the page with a filter already applied.

To be more specific I am looking at the website for  [NetCDF CF standard names](http://cfconventions.org/Data/cf-standard-names/28/build/cf-standard-name-table.html). From my page I would like to have link that would already filter e.g. for 'longitude' on the destination page.

The destination page is using javascript to apply the filter function.

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to control a JS on a site from an external URL.

But you can do a something else: Download the data from the external site to your server via a server-side script (like php), and recreate the filters on your site in JS. But this way you should care about copyrights and you have to maintain your script if they changed the table structure they used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - pity it does not work as I would like it to :(. Now to follow this up. If I create a "copy" on my own server, how would I then be able to create the required filters, as the JS is still in place? Or do I need to kind of integrate the content into my own page?

Comment: @red_tiger: You can recreate the JS from scratch (if you know jQuery it's relatively easy), or you can copy the JS code from the site, but I think it's not too ethic. Just for your information, if you integrate the site into an iFrame you still can't control it, but if you print out the content of it, it probably will work, but I think it's a copyright issue.

Comment: @red_tiger: To explain why it can't be done: Think if any site can control any JS on other sites. You open your bank account in a tab, then an another site in another tab send some money to somebody... Search for Cross-Site-Scripting (XSS), that used as an exploit to do hacks on sites. So there would be chaos, if it could be done. :)

Comment: thanks for that explanation. Indeed I just want something simple and practical done, but someone else might want to go just that bit further ... :). I have access to the information in an xml file, so looks like I will need to include it somehow different.

Comment: If you have the XML you can easily setup a site like that one. For example, try [Datatables](http://www.datatables.net/), I think it can do all the things you need.